# Como posso tornar esta url mais amigável ainda?

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Estou desenvolvendo **[este site](http://dent.axitech.com.br/tratamentos/aparelhos-dentarios__35)** e estudando um pouco sobre url's amigáveis já que era um usuário do Wordpress e agora estou passando para frameworks e sistemas. O que eu quero saber é se a url apresentada abaixo pode ser mais amigável ainda.

O método que pensei em usar inicialmente foi colocar o `id` do link do fim do post e recuperar este ID na página de destino ***tratamento.php***. Mas ai eu pensei ...

**Pergunta:** Será que esta url pode ser mais amigável ainda e não ter esse parametro no final? De qual outra forma eu poderia fazer isto?

***URL***: `http://dent.axitech.com.br/tratamentos/aparelhos-dentarios__35`

***HTACCESS***:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^home(.*) index.php
RewriteRule ^contato(.*) contato.php
RewriteRule ^tratamentos/(.*) tratamentos.php?tratamentos=$1
```

Comment: Talvez usando GET ou POST. Ex: http://dent.axitech.com.br/tratamentos/aparelhos-dentarios?param=35 (GET) Depois você pode redirecionar para uma url que não tenha o parâmetro no final. Isso vai depender de se você precisa que ele esteja ali.

Comment: Acho que essa instrução não modifica a url a ponto de remover o parâmetro então seria quase a mesma coisa que fiz, não?

Comment: Como passaria isso por $_POST?

Comment: Ao invés de usar um link, você usaria um form com botão submit e input hidden.

Comment: O Wordpress cria a cada postagem uma tag unica para aquele post. E usa essa tag na url. No caso você criaria um texto único.

Comment: @touchmx você me deu uma ideia e ao mesmo tempo me confundiu porque eu posso comparar as tags previamente criadas MAS se eu inserir um segundo **artigo** que seja com a mesma **tag** vamos ter problemas né. Como evitar que uma **tag** seja repetida no ato do cadastro do **artigo**?

Comment: Mas aí depende do tipo de conteudo que tu insere. No WP ele entende que nenhuma postagem tem o mesmo título que outra.